How to match a string not surrounded by brackets and parenthesis using regex
I have a collection of strings that take, for example, the following form:
(GOOGL)  [ST]S (partial) 02/01/2024 03/01/2024 $1,001 - $15,000

(PHG)  [ST]P 02/12/2024 03/01/2024 $1,001 - $15,000

(PFE)  [ST] P 02/12/2024 03/01/2024 $1,001 - $15,000

(UL)
[ST]S 02/12/2024 03/01/2024 $1,001 - $15,000

I'd like to find a pattern to return the thirdmost group of characters (eg, 'S' in the first line) not surrounded by brackets or parens for each row.
The below pattern gets me each of the capitalized character strings (eg, GOOG, ST, S):
([A-Z]+)

How would I only return the 'S', 'P', 'P', and 'S' from each line respectively, which will never be surrounded by parentheses or brackets (alternatively, will have at least one of, sometimes both, a space before or after)?

Could the string begin "(PHG) S P ...", "S (PHG) P ..." or "([PHG] R) S P ..."? If so, should "P" be returned in all three cases?

What if the "thirdmost group of characters" happens to be in brackets? Like, (a) (b) (c) d e f -- what do you return from such a string?  (Nothing -- no match?)  Is such a case possible in your data?

It's not possible...if it happens, it's an error and can be omitted/excluded

Conditions are not very clear... the answer will be as precise as you describe the task and your data... Does the position actually matter? Can there occur spaces inside parentheses? Just uppercase letters that are followed by a whitespace or end? E.g. [A-Z]+(?!\S)

You can use an alternation regex pattern that matches both bracket-enclosed text and capital letters but only captures capital letters so you can then filter out empty captures:
import re

s = '''
(GOOGL)  [ST]S (partial) 02/01/2024 03/01/2024 $1,001 - $15,000

(PHG)  [ST]P 02/12/2024 03/01/2024 $1,001 - $15,000

(PFE)  [ST] P 02/12/2024 03/01/2024 $1,001 - $15,000
'''
print(list(filter(None, re.findall(r'\([^)]*\)|\[[^]]*]|([A-Z]+)', s))))

This outputs:
['S', 'P', 'P']


Thanks...when I use the referenced pattern, on just the (PFE) entry, I get the below:  ```t
Out[180]: '(PFE)  [ST] P 02/12/2024 03/01/2024 $1,001 - $15,000'
rx.findall(r'([^)])|[[^]]]|([A-Z]+)', t)
Out[181]: ['', '', 'P']```

You need to filter out the empty captures with the filter function as suggested by my answer.

I assume that the third "group of characters" must be un-bracketed, or there is no match.
This is clearly the third group from the beginning of the string so match will do.  If lines of real data can have other text first then replace match with search (and then there's no need for the optional leading spaces used in the patterns below).
I take it that the last line in the question's data means that they are (somehow) getting a multiline string as one line of input.  I leave out their second line since it has the same structure as the first one. Then I add a couple of different lines.
import re

lines = ( 
    '(GOOGL)  [ST]S (partial)',
    '(PFE)  [ST] P 02/12/202',
    '(a) (b) (c) d',
    'A B C D', 
    '(UL)\n[ST]S 02/12/2024' )

for s in lines:
    # A character group, bracketed or not + another + an unbracketed one
    m = re.match( 
        r'\s*'  # possible leading spaces
        r'(?: \([A-Z]+\) | \[[A-Z]+] | [A-Z]+ )\s*'
        r'(?: \([A-Z]+\) | \[[A-Z]+] | [A-Z]+ )\s*'
        r'( [a-zA-Z]+ )\s*',
        s, re.X)

    if m:
        print(m.groups())
    else:
        print('No match')

Prints as expected
('S',)
('P',)
No match
('C',)
('S',)

I use a character group for a capital, [A-Z], per the question.  Adjust as needed.  Note how the re.X flag (VERBOSE) allows to space out the patterns; very useful for readability.
That repetition of patterns may be unsightly, and can get unworkable if there's more. Instead, we can build patterns from components programmatically
# a Group of Characters, bracketed or not
gc = re.compile(r'(?: \([A-Z]+\) | \[[A-Z]+] | [A-Z]+ )\s*', re.X)

for s in lines:
    m = re.match(r'\s*' + gc.pattern * 2 + r'([A-Z]+)', s, re.X)

    if m:
        print(m.groups())
    else:
        print('No match')

Prints the same as above.
There are a few further (mild) assumptions about data, and some edge cases here, and perhaps more to tweak, in both versions.  But they should be good for the shown use case.

Regex pattern works for this:
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'\([^)]*\)\s*\[[^\]]*\]\s*([A-Z])\s')

